# Uvicorn with reload=True not running against database in FastApi app

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn, lmdb

The program module is a fastapi app running on uvicorn with access to an lmdb database. For development (on Windows 11), reload=True is set on uvicorn. It appears uvicorn calls the database handle creation statement twice which leads to an lmdb error (as it can only be called once). Note, this takes place before any changes are made to the code for reload to be triggered.

With reload=False, uvicorn runs as expected and access to the database via fastapi works. Output of both options are shown below. How is this problem solved?

reload=True

```
db = lmdb.Environment(dbname, dbpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run('myprogram:app', host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="debug", reload=True,)

INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\dines']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [15480] using StatReload

lmdb.Error: C:/Users/dines/data: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.
```

reload=False

```
db = lmdb.Environment(dbname, dbpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run('myprogram:app', host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="debug", reload=False,)

INFO:     Started server process [16860]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: When you're using `reload=True`, uvicorn starts a second thread that imports the code - again - so your module will be loaded twice (which is why you have to guard the uvicorn startup with `__name__ == "__main__"`). A possible solution would be to use the `uvicorn` command to start your application instead of using the in-python solution, but you might also want to look at using the startup/shutdown events of FastAPI: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/ - or possibly use the dependency system in FastAPI - I'm not familiar enough with lmdb to say what the ideal solution would be.

Comment: But,  __name__ == "__main__" is being used? The module is called from the command line with arguments so I don't believe a startup event is applicable. FastAPI's dependency injection is used but the uvicorn problem still occurs.

Comment: Yes, it's being used _the first time_ - since the lmdb call is _outside_ of the name guard, it'll run both times. When I'm talking about using `uvicorn` directly, I mean running `uvicorn name:app --reload` instead of using the in-module call to launch uvicorn, in that case your code will only be loaded once (since the module won't run, and THEN start uvicorn - uvicorn will import and start your application in a single operation). The startup/shutdown events gets triggered _when the FastAPI server starts_, so they might work for what you want.

Comment: Reviewed the uvicorn documentation but cannot see how to pass user arguments by running uvicorn from the command line?

Comment: I'll work on passing the command line arguments to the uvicorn startup/shutdown events and see if it works. Later ...

Comment: "The startup/shutdown events gets triggered when the FastAPI server starts" - Yes, this worked. uvicorn is started programmatically with reload=True; command line arguments are passed into the uvicorn startup event which performs the various initial processing including configuring a dependency injection. Thank-you :)

Comment: `uvicorn myprogram:app --reload --port 8000 --log-level debug --host 0.0.0.0` would be the same as your call to `uvicorn.run` in your code; use `uvicorn --help` to see all options.

Comment: @MatsLindh If you can answer with something like """With reload=True, uvicorn starts a second thread that imports the code - again - so the module will be loaded twice (which is why you have to guard the uvicorn startup with __name__ == "__main__"). One solution is to use the startup/shutdown events of FastAPI: fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events which get triggered when the FastAPI server starts. Command line arguments can be passed to the startup event too.""", I will then accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're starting uvicorn inside your module file, the file will be read twice - once when you're invoking the module yourself through `python`, and once when `uvicorn` starts up (it'll also have to read the module you've given it).

You can [use FastAPI's `startup` event to trigger code to only run when the server itself is starting up](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/):

```py
databases = {}

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    databases["db"] = lmdb.Environment(dbname, dbpath)
```

Another option is to invoke uvicorn from the CLI instead of using the same Python module. Most of your options will transfer over directly:

```
uvicorn myprogram:app --reload --port 8000 --log-level debug --host 0.0.0.0
```

This will also only invoke the code once, since you're now launching uvicorn directly without first loading your module.

Comment: Got it working programatically and from the CLI. Thank-you :)